# Controller manager service not available for ros2

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu

I am working on ros2 (dist-foxy) for developing a robotic arm and trying to launch a controller file.I have installed all the necessary dependencies but after launching the controller file there is an error due to timeout which is due to unavailable controller services [ though gazebo window opens without any controller property].

```
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [gazebo-1]: process started with pid [18236]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-2]: process started with pid [18238]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [18240]
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-4]: process started with pid [18242]
[INFO] [spawner.py-5]: process started with pid [18244]
[INFO] [spawner.py-6]: process started with pid [18246]
[robot_state_publisher-3] [WARN] [1653424684.281280051] [robot_state_publisher]: No robot_description parameter, but command-line argument available.  Assuming argument is name of URDF file.  This backwards compatibility fallback will be removed in the future.
[ros2_control_node-4] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
[ros2_control_node-4]   what():  invalid URDF passed in to robot parser
[robot_state_publisher-3] Parsing robot urdf xml string.
[robot_state_publisher-3] Link base_link had 1 children
[robot_state_publisher-3] Link link_1 had 1 children
[robot_state_publisher-3] Link link_2 had 1 children
[robot_state_publisher-3] Link link_3 had 1 children
[robot_state_publisher-3] Link link_4 had 1 children
[robot_state_publisher-3] Link link_5 had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1653424684.286684548] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1653424684.286729555] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link_1
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1653424684.286744506] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link_2
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1653424684.286756599] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link_3
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1653424684.286768971] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link_4
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1653424684.286781041] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link_5
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1653424684.286793463] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment world
[spawner.py-5] [INFO] [1653424684.355840757] [rrbot.spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[spawner.py-6] [INFO] [1653424684.386594419] [rrbot.spawner_joint_trajectory_controller]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[spawn_entity.py-2] [INFO] [1653424684.606974784] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-2] [INFO] [1653424684.607804417] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity XML from file /home/arnob/robotic_arm_ws/install/big_bazu/share/big_bazu/urdf/big_bazu.urdf
[spawn_entity.py-2] [INFO] [1653424684.610780892] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-2] [INFO] [1653424684.611217592] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[gazebo-1] [INFO] [1653424685.331272045] [gazebo_ros_node]: ROS was initialized without arguments.
[spawn_entity.py-2] [INFO] [1653424685.366494615] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-2] [INFO] [1653424685.572130985] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [big_bazu]
[spawn_entity.py-2] [INFO] [1653424685.572585039] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for shutdown to delete entity [big_bazu]
[ERROR] [ros2_control_node-4]: process has died [pid 18242, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/foxy/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node --ros-args -r __ns:=/rrbot --params-file /tmp/launch_params_f11v2lzm --params-file /home/arnob/robotic_arm_ws/install/big_bazu/share/big_bazu/config/jtc.yaml'].
[spawner.py-5] [INFO] [1653424686.365885628] [rrbot.spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[spawner.py-6] [INFO] [1653424686.397118830] [rrbot.spawner_joint_trajectory_controller]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[spawner.py-5] [INFO] [1653424688.380758834] [rrbot.spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[spawner.py-6] [INFO] [1653424688.411129098] [rrbot.spawner_joint_trajectory_controller]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[spawner.py-5] [INFO] [1653424690.400372175] [rrbot.spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[spawner.py-6] [INFO] [1653424690.431781233] [rrbot.spawner_joint_trajectory_controller]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[spawner.py-5] [INFO] [1653424692.419072689] [rrbot.spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[spawner.py-6] [INFO] [1653424692.450739887] [rrbot.spawner_joint_trajectory_controller]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[spawner.py-5] [ERROR] [1653424694.438125274] [rrbot.spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Controller manager not available
[spawner.py-6] [ERROR] [1653424694.467691750] [rrbot.spawner_joint_trajectory_controller]: Controller manager not available
[ERROR] [spawner.py-5]: process has died [pid 18244, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/foxy/lib/controller_manager/spawner.py joint_state_broadcaster --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args -r __ns:=/rrbot'].
[ERROR] [spawner.py-6]: process has died [pid 18246, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/foxy/lib/controller_manager/spawner.py joint_trajectory_controller -c /controller_manager --ros-args -r __ns:=/rrbot'].
```

Even after the gazebo window opens when i run
$ ros2 topic list

It does not show the necessary controllers e.g
joint_trajectory_controller

Comment: Can you post the repo you got this code from? Need more information to help debug

Answer (score 1):

Check if your gazebo has the required library

- apt-get install ros-foxy-gazebo-ros2-control